# Scala template form values are reset

Tags: playframework-2.1, scala-template

Using Play 2.1 Java version

I have a simple form

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @inputText(userForm("usercode"), args = 'placeholder -> "User Code",'class -> "form-control input-sm",'_label -> "User Code")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @inputText(userForm("username"), args = 'placeholder -> "User Name",'class -> "form-control input-sm",'_label -> "User Name")
    </div>
```

When the User submits the Form and if Errors Exists the Form inputted data is lost.

At my controller

```
 Form<User> userForm= Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
  if (userForm.hasErrors()) {
            Logger.info("Erros in Form");
            return badRequest(
                    userAdd.render("Add User",userForm)
            );
    }
```

Question :

How to retrieve the values back to the form ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the form to the view again as a common templates param.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understood it fully.

Comment: I think I'm sending the form back again check this line  ` return badRequest(
                    userAdd.render("Add User",userForm)
            );`